# I want to match both fields but every time i run this script so ans comes in false please check my code or logic

Tags: javascript

html part :

```
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Email" />
<input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password" />
<button type="submit" onclick="validateUser()">Submit</button>
<p id="para"></p>
```

JavaScript part :

```
var USERS = ['sumair', 'awais', 'umair'];
var PASSWORDS = [1234, 1234, 1234]

function validateUser() {
    var username = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('pass').value;

    for (var i in USERS) {
        if (username == USERS[i] && password == PASSWORDS[i]) {
            document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = "you are in";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = "you are not in";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to `break` loop  when the condition is achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i in USERS) {
    if (username == USERS[i] && password == PASSWORDS[i]) {
        document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = "you are in";
        break;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = "you are not in";
    }
}
```

Comment: why we need to use break please explain

Comment: If you don't use break, the loop will continue and will set the 'para' element to "you are not in".  You want the loop to stop when you have reached the condition you are looking for

Comment: if first user was that we enter, then result will be ok, then 2 times result will overwrite it to `not in`

Answer (score 3):

You need to [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) loop  when the condition is achieved.

```
//Create a variable
var result = false;
for (var i in USERS) {
    if (username == USERS[i] && password == PASSWORDS[i]) {
        result = true;
        break;
    }
}

//Based on the basis of result. 
if (result) {
    document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = "you are in";
} else {
    document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = "you are not in";
}
```